# rails select from association using join

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models: company, event, event_space

company has many events
event belongs to event space

now I want to get all events from a company where the event_space has virtual attribute set to true

```
c = Comapny.first
c.events.joins(:event_space).where("event_space.virtual = true")
```

I'm doing something wrong because I have

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: event_space.virtual: SELECT "events".* FROM "events" INNER JOIN "event_spaces" ON "event_spaces"."id" = "events"."event_space_id" WHERE "events"."company_id" = 2 AND (event_space.virtual = true)

Comment: try `event_spaces.virtual = true`  (plural)

Comment: why don't you do `Events.where(comapny_id: c.id).where("event_space.virtual = true")

Comment: @Alireza not working, the same error

Comment: @MoisesZaragoza not working, we cannot access event_spaces in this way, we need to use joins in this case I think

Comment: this should work: `c.events.joins(:event_space).where(event_spaces: {virtual: true})`

Comment: @Alireza yes, this works, can you please post it like an answer and I'll accept it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your `where` clause as follows to get it right:

```
c.events.joins(:event_space).where(event_spaces: {virtual: true})
```